# Numerical Problems Based On Vernier Callipers

Tags: experimental-physics, measurements, error-analysis, measurement-problem, instrument

I watched a [video on Vernier Calipers](https://youtu.be/vkPlzmalvN4) which gave me an understanding of how it works and how to read a Vernier Caliper. I also tried the [GeoGebra simulation](https://www.geogebra.org/m/DemUu87n). But I am not able to understand the formula (**least count** and **zero error** formula) required to do numerical problems. Please explain the formula with an example numerical. For instance, I am not able to do the following problem which was asked in IIT JEE 2016:
[image: IIT JEE 2016]

---

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vernier_scale#Least_count_or_vernier_constant:

> The difference between the value of one main scale division and the value of one vernier scale division is known as the **least count** of the vernier, also known as the **vernier constant**.

$$\text{Least Count of Vernier Calipers} = {1\text{MSD (Main Scale Division)}\over1\text{VSD (Vernier Scale Division)}}$$
or
$$\text{Least Count of Vernier Calipers} = {1\text{MSD (Main Scale Division)}\over\text{Number of divisions in Vernier Scale}}$$

I understood least count but I am not able to understand the length of (n − 1) main-scale divisions = the length of n vernier-scale division (IIT JEE 2003), or
$$(n − 1)S = nV$$, or
$$nS − S = nV$$.

I am also not able to understand the **Zero error** formula $\text{Zero error} (ZE) = ±n × \text{least count} (LC)$ and method to use a vernier scale or caliper with zero error is to use the formula $\text{actual reading} = \text{main scale} + \text{vernier scale} − (\text{zero error})$.

---

[image: VernierscaleHow a vernier scale works.gif]
[image: Vernier scale zero error +0.10.gif]

(Images uploaded by User:Lookang, Wikipedia)

Comment: I am solving the numerical problems from https://www.scribd.com/document/416066050/Numerical-Problems-Based-on-Vernier-Callipers If you are not able to access the document (if you don't have Scribd subscription) I can send you the document as an attachment.

Comment: Nobody in their right mind would ever make a real Vernier caliper with a scale like your C2 example. And the drawings in the question are so inaccurate they are ridiculous IMO.